# Get index of clicked element

Tags: javascript

So I'm still pretty new at JavaScript, I can do some basic stuff, but a lot of it, not so much. Anyway I am trying to create a gallery that opens a larger slideshow when one of the elements is clicked. The problem I'm running into is I don't know how to find the index of the clicked elements. I've tried Google, and I even looked here and lots of answers to the question, but none of them seem to work for my bit of code.

```
    var getThumbs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.retail-thumbnail'));
    for (var i = 0; i < getThumbs.length; i++) {
        getThumbs[i].onclick = function(e) {
            var createSlideshow = document.createElement('div');
            createSlideshow.setAttribute('class', 'retail-slideshow');
            var createClsBtn = document.createElement('div');
            createClsBtn.setAttribute('class', 'close');
            createClsBtn.innerHTML = '&times;';
            createSlideshow.append(createClsBtn);
            var slides = '';
            const index = getThumbs
            getThumbs.forEach(gall => {
                if (gall.classList.contains('video-thumb')) {
                    gall.childNodes.forEach(source => {
                            source = Array.from(source.src.split('.'));
                            source = source[source.length - 3];
                            slides += '<div class="retail-slide">\n' +
                                      '<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/' + source + '" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen></iframe>\n' +
                                      '</div>\n\n'
                    });
                } else {
                    slides += '<img src="' + gall.src + '" class="retail-slide">\n\n'
                }
            });
            slides += '<div id="retail_ss_prev"></div><div id="retail_ss_next"></div>';
            createSlideshow.innerHTML += slides;
            var activeModal = document.querySelector('.modal.active');
            activeModal.append(createSlideshow);
            var activeCls = document.querySelector('.retail-slideshow > .close');
            activeCls.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                activeCls.parentNode.remove();
            });
        };
    };
};
```

So this is what I have, and it writes everything, but I can't get the index when I click on one of the .retail-thumbnail elements. Any help is greatly appreciated. Preferably in Vanilla JS. I try to stay away from Jquery

Comment: Possibly you could modify your function `plusSlides()` so that it takes a 2nd parameter: the `i` value of the loop, indicating the current slide.

Comment: Do you mean i inside getThumbs[i].onclick?

Comment: @RahulDwivedi, I meant the same `i` of the for loop, where `plusSlides()` would be called with this value of `i` as the 2nd parameter, and `plusSlides()` would have logic to handle the 2nd value representing the index of the slide.

Comment: @GetSet I don't seem to see `plusSlides ` in the code. However, check my answer if that's what you mean

Comment: @RahulDwivedi, it was in there originally -- looks like the OP removed that bit on an edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take advantage of closures.

```
var getThumbs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.retail-thumbnail'));
for (var i = 0; i < getThumbs.length; i++) {
    getThumbs[i].onclick = function(index) {
        return function(e) {
            //Your current function, where index now is the same as i at the moment of assigning the event listener
        };
    }(i);
}
```

Or, you could add a data attribute to each element, either in the html (something like `data-index="1"`), or setting them from js:

```
var getThumbs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.retail-thumbnail'));
for (var i = 0; i < getThumbs.length; i++) {
    getThumbs[i].dataset.index=i;
    getThumbs[i].onclick = function(e) {
        var index=this.dataset.index;
        //....
    };
}
```

Comment: The first code set is the answer without using ES-6 fat arrow functions or anonymous functions, as I referenced in my arrow. As Gabriel shows, you create a function inside of a function and then execute it immediately.

Comment: This is what I needed. I wasn't aware of dataset,index, so that's something to add to my notes. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Use an anonymous function to pass both the event and the index.

Below is the code that passes the index to the function in your code, in addition to the event.

By using an anonymous function, your are able to create a function that takes the event as an input (e), but also know what the index is (see about closures - the anonymous function knows lexical scope from when it was created).

I used anonymous function and the ES-6 fat arrow function syntax below ()=>{}. You can do it without these, but it will look less clean.

```
const clicked = (e,i) =>{
        var createSlideshow = document.createElement('div');
            createSlideshow.setAttribute('class', 'retail-slideshow');
            var createClsBtn = document.createElement('div');
            createClsBtn.setAttribute('class', 'close');
            createClsBtn.innerHTML = '&times;';
            createSlideshow.append(createClsBtn);
            var slides = '';
            const index = getThumbs
            getThumbs.forEach(gall => {
                if (gall.classList.contains('video-thumb')) {
                    gall.childNodes.forEach(source => {
                            source = Array.from(source.src.split('.'));
                            source = source[source.length - 3];
                            slides += '<div class="retail-slide">\n' +
                                      '<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/' + source + '" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen></iframe>\n' +
                                      '</div>\n\n'
                    });
                } else {
                    slides += '<img src="' + gall.src + '" class="retail-slide">\n\n'
                }
            });
            slides += '<div id="retail_ss_prev"></div><div id="retail_ss_next"></div>';
            createSlideshow.innerHTML += slides;
            var activeModal = document.querySelector('.modal.active');
            activeModal.append(createSlideshow);
            var activeCls = document.querySelector('.retail-slideshow > .close');
            activeCls.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            activeCls.parentNode.remove();
}


var getThumbs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.retail-thumbnail'));
    for (var i = 0; i < getThumbs.length; i++) {
        getThumbs[i].onclick = (e) =>{clicked(e,i);}
        };
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
for (var i=0; i<5; i++){
  var abc = function(){

    alert(i) //You can very well access i here
  }

 abc();

}
```

You can pretty much access `i` inside `getThumbs[i].onclick` without having to write extra lines of codes.

```
for (var i = 0; i < getThumbs.length; i++) {
        getThumbs[i].onclick = function(e) {
            var createSlideshow = document.createElement('div');
            var index = i //You can access i due to the lexical scope
}
```